# How to evaluate $\frac{d}{dx} (3x + 1)^{\frac{3}{2}}(2x + 4)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I'm supposed to use the product rule to differentiate:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} (3x + 1)^{\frac{3}{2}}(2x + 4).
$$

This gives me:
$$
2(3x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{9}{2}(2x + 4)(3x + 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$

My problem is that i'm now supposed to somehow factorise this answer to match the one in the back of the book and I don't know how:
$$
5(3x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}} (3x + 4).
$$

The fractional indicies are confusing me the most when it comes to factorizing, please help me. *^_^*

*Thank you for your time~!*

Comment: Take out $(3x+1)^{1/2}$ from the whole thing. Also notice that $(3x+1)^{3/2}=(3x+1)(3x+1)^{1/2}$

Comment: I see! Thank you @Adam I'll start with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2\color{red}{(3x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}} + \frac{9}{2}(2x + 4)(3x + 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=2\color{red}{(3x+1)}\color{blue}{(3x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}+ \frac{9}{2}(2x + 4)\color{blue}{(3x + 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$ Factor $(3x + 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ out, $$=\color{blue}{(3x + 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}[(6x+2)+(9x+18)]=(3x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}5(3x + 4).$$

Comment: Awesome this makes perfect sense now! Thank you so much :) @poyea

Answer (score 1):

First notice that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(ax+b)^n=an(ax+b)^{n-1}$$
Let $p=(3x+1)^{\frac32}\to p'=3(\frac32)(3x+1)^{\frac32-1}=\frac92(3x+1)^\frac12$

Let $q=2x+4\to q'=2$

Then via product rule:
$$\frac{d(pq)}{dx}=p'q+q'p$$

*The letters are interchangeable, I like $p$ and $q$, others like $u$ and $v$, etc*

We get:
$$\frac{d[(3x+1)^\frac32(2x+4)]}{dx}=\frac92(3x+1)^\frac12(2x+4)+2(3x+1)^\frac32$$
We can then simplify this to:
$$(3x+1)^\frac12\bigg[9(x+2)+2(3x+1)\bigg]$$
$$\to(3x+1)^\frac12(15x+20)\to5(3x+1)^\frac12(3x+4)$$